# Two dimensional char array in a text file having empty spaces in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

**I have a text file that contains team results of medals, each line represents the total medals of a team in five games, and each char is the medal in a single game:**

```
GSGBS
SSBGG
G SB
```

**I used scanner to turn file into a String:**

```
String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
Scanner teamMedals = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
```

Then I used a while loop to print the medals of each team:

```
    int teamNumber = 0;
    while (teamMedals.hasNext()) {
         String x = teamMedals.nextLine();
         teamNumber += 1;
         System.out.println("Team #" + teamNumber + "medals: " + x);
    }
```

I created this empty two dimensional array to be populated by the scores:

```
int numberOfGames = 5
char [] [] teamScoresArray = new char [teamNumber][numberOfGames.length];
```

I need to populate each sub array element with a single char of each team.
so the outcome would look like this:

```
[['G','S','G','B','S'],['S','S','B','G','G'],['G',' ','S','B',' ']]
```

The problem is, since there are empty spaces and new lines I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: I think you can't use arrays, since you don't know the number of teams. at the start, so you can't create an array with the right size. You could use an ArrayList of Arrays

Comment: it's given at the beginning of the problem 3

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate the array?

Comment: I can't figure out one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for simple line-reading of a text file. Use a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for better performance.

```
char[][] array;
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    List<char[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; )
        list.add(line.toCharArray());
    array = list.toArray(new char[list.size()][]);
}
```

Better yet, use [`Files.lines(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) stream processing (Java 8+):

```
char[][] array = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                      .map(String::toCharArray)
                      .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

*Output*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

```
[[G, S, G, B, S], [S, S, B, G, G], [G,  , S, B,  ]]
```